# GCP-Cloud run Webhook and non webhook url

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have two endpoints in a cloud run java application as below

```
1) https://<serviceName>-<projectHash>-<region>.run.app/v1/blah

2) https://<serviceName>-<projectHash>-<region>.run.app/v1/webhook
```

The first one needs to be authenticated via a service account and the second one should bypass authentication via service account rather a token or a secret is passed to ensure that the incoming requests are from authorized services. Currently is this possible via Api gateway using static api key but is there any better solution for this?

Comment: You can't do that with Cloud Run. You need an addition layer to manage the security (API Gateway, APIGEE, whatever, but not in Cloud Run)

Answer (score 0):

As per answer of @guillaumeblaquiere:

> You can't do that with Cloud Run. You need an additional layer to manage the security (API Gateway, APIGEE, whatever, but not in Cloud Run)

You can check the following documentation for your reference:

- [Getting started with API Gateway and Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/get-started-cloud-run)
- [Send traffic to a VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc)
- [Cloud  Run Network security](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/security#network-security)